# Cloning a Linq to Sql Entity - detaching data context

Tags: linq-to-sql, clone, detach

I have a requirement to clone a Linq to SQL entity.  In overview:

```
Customer origCustomer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == 5);
Customer newCustomer = CloneUtils.Clone(origCustomer);
newCustomer.CustomerId = 0;  // Clear key
db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);
db.SubmitChanges();   // throws an error
```

where CloneUtils.Clone() is a simple generic method that uses reflection to copy the copy the data from the original entity to the new entity.

The problem I have is that when I try and add the new entity back into the database, I get the following error:

An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.

I can't seem to find an easy/generic way of detaching the cloned entity from the data context.  Or maybe I can adjust my cloning method to 'skip' the context related fields?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

For completeness, here is the method I ended up with following Marcus's advice:

```
public static T ShallowClone<T>(T srcObject) where T : class, new()
{
   // Get the object type
   Type objectType = typeof(T);

   // Get the public properties of the object
   PropertyInfo[] propInfo = srcObject.GetType()
      .GetProperties(
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
      );

   // Create a new  object
   T newObject = new T();

   // Loop through all the properties and copy the information 
   // from the source object to the new instance
   foreach (PropertyInfo p in propInfo)
   {
      Type t = p.PropertyType;
      if ((t.IsValueType || t == typeof(string)) && (p.CanRead) && (p.CanWrite))
      {
         p.SetValue(newObject, p.GetValue(srcObject, null), null);
      }
   }

   // Return the cloned object.
   return newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only clone public properties

```
var PropertyBindings = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
```

That are value types or string

```
var PropType = p.PropertyType.IsValueType || p.PropertyType == typeof(string);
```

And that are accessible

```
 var IsAccessible = p.CanRead && p.CanWrite;
```